# iPhone Memory Warning Problems with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, image, memory, uiscrollview, didreceivememorywarning

I am working on an iPad app that lets the user scroll through a number of images (usually around 20 .jpg files in a single horizontal scroll view). The file sizes are around 200 kb each. The images are set as the "Background" property of a UIButton because I wanted to allow the user to click the button to save the image. Every time I run the app, it crashes after scrolling for a little while. If you don't scroll, it behaves normal. I did run the app using the performance tools and didn't find any leaks.

I am getting a "Level=1" memory warning just before the app crashes. I had it running with about 8 images in the scrollview and never had a problem. So I know it has something to do with the scrollView and the images/buttons. In the "viewDidLoad" method, I simply did the following to set up the scrollView and then linked it in Interface Builder:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(5722, 340)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I added the images directly to the button in Interface Builder. Would it help if I deleted the background image, and instead set the backgrounds in the "viewDidLoad" method? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you need to do is create individual cells that these images live on, that get recycled like you'd get in a tableview. I have some code which does this that you may use for your purpose, or at least give it a go anyway. Works just like a tableview.

It's available [here](http://codaset.com/jer/jscrollingrow). This does the heavy lifting for you already, in that all you need to do is create one of these, slap it in a view somewhere, and create your individual cells. Those cells will be reused as you scroll so you won't need more than N + 2 cells loaded into memory at any one time, where N is the number that fit on your screen.

Comment: Thanks Jer. I looked at your code, but honestly, I don't have a clue where to begin. This is my first iPad/iPhone app (though I have been working on it for awhile as a secondary project) so I'm just learning this as I go. Do I just copy and past your code into my .h and .m files, or do I create new files with your code? I haven't done anything with tables so that is all new stuff for me to learn. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, well first what you'll want to do is get familiar with tableviews. They're used everywhere, and you'll use them a lot in other areas. The big thing with cell reuse you have to understand is that you need to clear your cell after it's reused, or if one cannot be reused, allocate a new one. What this does, is in cases where you're displaying images, for example, you only store in memory enough to supply the immediate need: The images on screen, and one either side of your scrollable area "preloaded" for users scrolling. The rest aren't loaded, so don't use up memory.

Comment: Also, the WWDC session 104 will help you in understanding how to implement cell reuse.

Comment: Is the JScrollingRowCell class just for future expansion, do I need it for what I am doing? Also your line numbers jump around. Is that code that I need to fill in or is everything being displayed a working class?

Comment: You subclass it in the similar way you'd subclass UITableviewCell. You'd put an image view on it, just like you would have in your code that's using a ton of memory, but only one image view.

Comment: Jer, thanks for your help. While I still don't completely understand your classes, the WWDC session 104 was really helpful. I am downloading the sample code for the WWDC and will finish working this out tomorrow. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

as jer wrote, the problem seems to be in the recycling. Make sure to remove, release and update the content of each cell every time you get a new one in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

(I would have commented jer's post but I'm unable to do this, probably because of my limited permissions).

Comment: Just to note, he's not using a tableview. He wants horizontal scrolling capabilities, and UITableView doesn't do that.